# Gradle sync in IntelliJ triggers tasks defined in build.gradle - why, and how to prevent that?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am currently doing some setup with proguard, for which I have defined a custom proguard task, as described in the tutorial I'm following. For creating some copies that I need I have defined some helper tasks, that I also want to use otherwise, or trigger them manually if necessary. During debugging I encountered some weird behaviour of gradle/IntelliJ. It seems that my helper tasks are always executed, when reloading gradle via the sync button, which seems curious to me.

I have defined my tasks in the build.gradle, so I created a simple dummy task in their place:

```
task test123() {
    println "Testing Testing"
}
```

When syncing gradle, I do indeed get the following output:

```
> Configure project :
This mapping 'stable_20' was designed for MC 1.8.8! Use at your own peril.
Testing Testing
WARNING: You are using an unsupported version of ForgeGradle.
Please consider upgrading to ForgeGradle 5 and helping in the efforts to get old versions working on the modern toolchain.
See https://gist.github.com/TheCurle/fe7ad3ede188cbdd15c235cc75d52d4a for more info on contributing.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
```

I looked up my issue online, and found several mentions of this feature actually being requested as such, because people wanted to enable this behaviour. Also I found the documentation of JetBrains at https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/#gradle-tasks-triggers-settings , which seems to control this behaviour, if e.g. you need to have your task executed specifically before/after the sync. Some other online post claims that you have to toggle the option in the sidebar... which is not the case.

This is how the sidebar looks, when everything is at default, if an option is toggled, there's a checkmark in front of the text.

[image]

I suspect that there is a respective setting somewhere hidden in the dephts of IntelliJ, but I really cant find it. If there is another way to prevent my tasks from being executed on reload, that would also be a solution. Also, why does this happen?

Comment: Do you use this [`gradle-idea-ext-plugin`](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin) plugin? Or `idea` [Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) in build scripts? These plugins may modify IDE project configuration files and influence behaviour. Also, if some task (e.g. the one that you have created) is configured to depend on some **task which is invoked during IDE Gradle sync** - it will also be triggered during sync.

Comment: You wrote "described in the tutorial I'm following". Can you share the tutorial link? It seems you're confusing Gradle's configuration from execution phase.

Comment: @thokuest https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203373890-Calling-a-Gradle-task-when-idea-refreshes-the-project

Comment: @Andrey I'm using neither of those two, and only ForgeGradle, shadow and proguard plugins. The test-task does not depend on any tasks, at least I have specified no dependency, so I think this is not the case.

Comment: From what I can tell, your dummy task works as expected. You don't have any actions (e.g. in a `doFirst` or `doLast` block), so you cannot see if it runs or not from the output alone. However, as @thokuest mentions, you have added a print statement to the _configuration_ of the task, and since you are also eagerly evaluating it through the `task name()` DSL, it will show up during sync. You can read up on the [build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) if you need to better understand the distinction between the two.